# Need to backup messages Nokia 501

Tags: backup, sync, smartphone, nokia

I need to connect my Nokia asha 501 to PC and backup the messages in it.
The Nokia Ovi Suite / Nokia PC Suite for Windows/Mac supports my phone but does not allow me backup messages.

Is there a software avilable on Ubuntu to **backup my messages** from my nokia asha 501?